# SlidingTabLayout text & background color customization

Tags: android, tabs, selector

first of all, when I select a tab, it only changes its color while I press it, but after the tab is selected the color stays as the color of unselected state.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

populateTabStrip() method:

```
tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.tab_text_color_selector));
```

Secondly, the background of the tab .. I can't figure out how to use a selector here.

** getColorStateList is deprecated, so any suggestions of replacing it would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**try that also please**

viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

```
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.CYAN));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.YELLOW));
                        break;

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: if I do that, once I select another tab , the last selected tab's background stays changed.
For example everything is white. I choose tab A, it becomes CYAN for example, then I choose tab B and tab A stays CYAN

Comment: and what is the tabLayout variable inside SlidingTabLayout?

Comment: when you create tabLayout  and you want to change the text color you dont need slidingTabLayout , only the code that i write to you

Comment: hope it helped you

Comment: sorry, I don't understand you. I'm using SlidingTabLayout, where did this TabLayout come from?

Answer (score -2):

**try this please**

tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));